# Can I enable SQLCMD mode from inside a script?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

Is there something like a directive which I can use in a script to force SSMS to enable/disable SQLCMD mode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As has been said, there isn't a way.

However, one thing we do is to include a quick check in our script header, to determine whether SQLCMD mode is on (and terminate the script if not):

```
:setvar DatabaseName "MyDatabase"
GO
IF ('$(DatabaseName)' = '$' + '(DatabaseName)')
    RAISERROR ('This script must be run in SQLCMD mode. Disconnecting.', 20, 1) WITH LOG
GO
-- The below is only run if SQLCMD is on, or the user lacks permission to raise fatal errors
IF @@ERROR != 0
    SET NOEXEC ON
GO

PRINT 'You will only see this when SQLCMD mode is on'
-- Rest of script goes here

GO
SET NOEXEC OFF
GO
```

There is a reason Severity 20 is used, it tends to kill the connection immediately, preventing any more script code from running, even if there are `GO` batch terminators later in the script.

> [Severities 20-24](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities):
>
> Indicate system problems and are fatal errors, which means that the Database Engine task that is executing a statement or batch is no longer running. The task records information about what occurred and then terminates. In most cases, **the application connection to the instance of the Database Engine may also terminate**. If this happens, depending on the problem, the application might not be able to reconnect.
>
> Error messages in this range can affect all of the processes accessing data in the same database and may indicate that a database or object is damaged. Error messages with a severity level from 19 through 24 are written to the error log.

Comment: For ssms the first 2 lines would be enough and for sql 2000 Query Analyzer it works, but the message is not displayed.

Comment: But wouldn't the script just continue executing from the next GO?

Comment: I'm using SSMS 2008 R2 and there the 2 lines produce: Meldung 102, Ebene 15, Status 1, Zeile 1
Incorrect syntax near ':'.
Using SQL Server 2000 Query Analyzer you need to use RAISERROR.

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8134305), you can also set `SET NOEXEC ON` as an added safety measure to prevent anything else in the script from running.

Comment: Hmm, this is using SQLCMD mode to find out if SQLCMD mode is on... I'd say it won't work properly when SQLCMD mode is off, as @bernd_k experienced. However, if :setvar is removed/replaced for SQL, it will then work.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 Unfortunately if the `:setvar` is removed, the `IF ('$(DatabaseName)'..` check will then result in a SQLCMD variable validation error when SQLCMD mode is enabled. The only way to avoid the `:setvar` error when SQLCMD is not enabled would be refer to a "known variable" that is guaranteed to be provided to the script (such as `$(SQLCMDDBNAME)` with sqlcmd.exe), however afaik SSMS doesn't currently have known variables.

Comment: @Dan Nolan: I see, somehow I missed the point of 3rd line. So if I understand it correctly, there's no solution to cover SQLCMD mode off. It will essentially display `incorrect syntax near ':'` because of `:setvar` at the beginning...

Comment: @Oak_3260548 Correct, the answer merely provides a way of stopping the script from executing if SQLCMD mode is not enabled. It's not a solution for detecting whether it is enabled as such.

Comment: This raises more questions than it answers. Ok - short answer to OP question is: no, you cannot enable SQLCMD mode from within a (TSQL) script. If I understand your additional info, none of the batches in the script will run if SQLCMD is disabled. First, the first line produces a TSQL syntax error - so the script is invalid to begin with. Second, if none of the remaining batches executes, why have a batch with `SET NOEXEC OFF`? Third, If I paste this into SSMS, remove `SET NOEXEC OFF` and run (with F5) then execute another query, the new query works. Why? NOEXEC should prevent it?

Comment: @youcantryreachingme `RAISERROR` severity level 20 (and above) is considered by SQL as a fatal error, which results in the connection being dropped immediately, hence no further batches (not even the `SET NOEXEC ON`) is executed. The reason why the `NOEXEC` statements are there is to cover the situation where the executing user does not have `sysadmin`/`ALTER TRACE` privileges, which is needed for raising fatal errors.

Answer (score 8):

No.

But you can always run in [SQLCMD mode and have T-SQL in it though](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx)

> To make a clear distinction between SQLCMD commands and Transact-SQL, all SQLCMD commands, need to be prefixed with a colon (:).

Comment: Is this still valid for SQL Server 2012 / 2014 / 2016?

Comment: @hot2use: Yes, I've used it on 2014/2016